# How to keep track of the seed

Tags: lua

So in Lua it's common knowledge that you can use `math.randomseed` but it's also obvious that `math.random` sets the seed as well (calling it twice does not return the same result), what does it set it to, and how can I keep track of it, and if it's impossible, please explain why that is so.

Comment: What exactly does keeping track of the seed mean to you? Keeping track of values set with `math.randomseed` + knowing initial seed value? Also your comment sounds like `math.random` sets the seed on successive calls and you want to track what it changes to - which might not be the case as seed may stay the same and a counter is used to produce different numbers from it.

Comment: You need some basic reading on RNG. This question is not Lua-specific.

Comment: @Oleg Not all RNG's are the same, I specifically talking about Lua's implementation.

Comment: 1) There's no "Lua implementation" - it just uses basic C library RNG. 2) according to your question you don't understand how seed works in RNG algorithms - this is a basic question that applies to most RNG out here. In short: you don't. Most RNG don't reveal to you their inner state.

Comment: `how can I keep track of it` - why do you want to?

Comment: @Nick Mostly for educational means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Lua question, but general question on how some RNG algorithm works.

First, Lua don't have their own RNG - they just output you (slightly mangled) value from RNG of underlying C library. Most RNG implementations do not reveal you their inner state, but sometimes you can caclulate it yourself.

For example when you use Lua on Windows, you'll be using [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)-based RNG from MS C library. The numbers you get is a slice of seed, not full value. There are two ways you can deal with that:

1. If you know how many times you called `random`, you can just take initial seed value, feed it to your copy of the same algorithm with same constants that are hardcoded in MS library and get exact value of seed.
2. If you don't, but you can be sure that nobody interferes in between your two calls to random, you can get two generated numbers, and reverse LCG algorithm by shifting bits back to their place. This will leave you with several missing bits (with one more bit thanks to Lua mangling) that you will need to simply bruteforce - just reiterate over all missing bits until your copy of algorithm produces exactly same two "random" numbers you've recorded before. That will be current seed stored inside library's RNG as well. Well programmed solution in Lua can bruteforce this in about 0.2-0.5s on somewhat dated PC - I did it past. Here's example on Crypto.SE talking about this task in more details: [Predicting values from a Linear Congruential Generator](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2086/31763).

First approach can be used with any other RNG algorithm that doesn't use any real entropy, second with most RNGs that don't mask too much bits in slice to make bruteforcing unreasonable.

Real answer though is: you don't need to keep track of seed at all. What you want is probably something else.

Comment: I 100% agree with your last statement. This is purely for educational means.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a seed all numbers `math.random()` generates are pseudo-random (This is always the case as the system will generate a seed by itself).

```
math.randomseed(4)
print(math.random())
print(math.random())
math.randomseed(4)
print(math.random())
```

Outputs

```
0.50827539156303
0.75454387490399
0.50827539156303
```

So if you reset the seed to the same value you can predict all values that are going to come up to the maximum number of consecutive values that you already generated using that seed.

What the seed does not do is keep the output of `math.random()` the same. It would be the same if you kept resetting it to the same value.

### An analogy as an example

Imagine the random number is an integer between 0 and 9 (instead of a double between 0 and 1). 
`math.random()` could traverse pi's decimals from an arbitrary starting position (default could be system time).
What you do when you use `set.seed()` is (not literally, this is an analogy as mentioned) set the starting decimals of where in pi you are going to retrieve your numbers.
If you now reset the seed to the same starting position the numbers are going to be the same as the last time you reset the starting position.
You will know the numbers of to the last call, after that you can't be certain anymore.

Comment: I understand basic knowledge of RNG's work. But when you call random, it sets a NEW position within pi, how can I keep track of this position? (Of course in reality, not this anology)